# How can I use a Gurumukhi font to typeset Punjabi with XeLaTeX or PDFLatex?

Tags: xetex, languages, indic

Folks I'm having a hard time using a non-English font with my LaTeX file. I've struggled for the last few days without success.
Some background I'm using Kile on Windows (with MikTeX). I know I need to compile with XeLateX for some reason and yes, I am doing that. I need to type a few sentences in  the Gurumukhi/Punjabi font. After this sentence things don't make much sense to me. This font is available as i) `.ttf` file and I have it installed on my computer, ii)  on CTAN here:https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gurmukhi-singh, and iii) as an `.itx` file here: http://www.aczoom.com/itrans/html/pundoc/pundoc.html . I have no idea what to do with the font, however.

Can someone provide detailed instructions on how to use it for someone who is not well-versed in installing stuff on `.tex`? Also: I can type in Punjabi that is not an issue; i.e., I do not need any transliterations - just how to get it into my tex file.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal non-Working Example which we can copy-paste and compile to reproduce the problem.  Please describe the problem, including the exact error message, if applicable. In that case, compiling the code you post should allow us to reproduce that exact error. Please provide a link for the truetype version of the font if it is freely available. The version on CTAN is designed for use with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX. Also, please consider making your subject line more descriptive e.g. 'How can I use a TTF Gurumukhi font to typeset Punjabi with XeLaTeX?'

Comment: You don't need to use the `gurmukhi-singh` package at all if you know Punjabi and have the appropriate font. Here's an example for Bengali [How can I use Bengali script in an English document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285507). The principle is exactly the same for Punjabi. Just write your Punjabi text directly. There's no need for transliteration packages.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think the OP is trying to use the font there. At least, that's how I understood it. But it is MetaFont is the problem.

Comment: @cfr But he says that the font is a `.ttf` so it can be installed as a regular system font and used with XeLaTeX.  If that's mistaken, then http://guca.sourceforge.net/typography/fonts/ seems to have an opentype Punjabi font that would work too (possibly better.)

Comment: @AlanMunn The OP says the font is available in 3 forms: as TTF, on CTAN and as `itx` (?). At least, that's how I understood it. Not the same font, I assume, but a suitable font. OK. The last one is type1 postscript, I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn I can type Punjabi and that is not a problem. (I should have specified that in the question and will edit it now). The issue is how to get it into Tex. I know babel and polyglossia do somethings too..

Comment: @AlanMunn So the Bengali link you provide says `\setotherlanguage{bengali}` . Shouldn't that change for Punjabi?

Comment: It will be a bit more complicated than that, since `polyglossia` at the moment does not support Punjabi as a language.  Also, the Saab font may have some problems (not sure of that yet).

Comment: @AlanMunn Yep. So do you have any other suggestions, perhaps using the links I provided or others (maybe like Babel)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the Saab font. I don't know anything about the Gurmukhi script, and the Saab font doesn't seem to recognize the Gurmukhi script tag, even though it should, so there may be problems with the font.  For small sections of Punjabi text, this may be sufficient. For whole documents you would need to write your own version of a `polyglossia` `.ldf` file for Punjabi, but this is not really a beginner's task, unfortunately.

(If there are major problems with the output of this, (apart from the bad Google translation) please let me know in the comments and I will delete the answer.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\punjabifont{Saab}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textpunjabi}{\punjabifont}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\textpunjabi{ ਇਹ ਇੱਕ ਦੀ ਸਜ਼ਾ ਜੋ ਕਿ ਹੈ ਬੁਰੀ} Google \textpunjabi{ਦੁਆਰਾ ਅਨੁਵਾਦ ਕੀਤਾ ਗਿਆ ਹੈ.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wow. This is much farther than I ever got too in two days. Don't delete your answer :P I get an error: The font "Saab" cannot be found. How did you compile it??

Comment: Okay for my last comment, I just needed to install the Saab font on my Windows (separate from .tex). Now I don't get any errors, but the pdf displays question marks instead of Punjabi; i.e., 
1 A section
?? ??? ?? ???? ?? ?? ?? ???? Google ????? ?????? ???? ???
??.

Comment: Two things: your file must be encoded UTF-8, and you must compile with XeLaTeX (not pdfLaTeX).

Comment: I am using XeLatex. But I don't know how to check if my .tex file is UTF-8 encoded or not. And if not, how to make it into one.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with your viewer in Kile? (I don't know anything about Kile (or Windows, for that matter, but I don't think this is a Windows problem.) What happens if you open the PDF file with Acrobat Reader or an equivalent?

Comment: Oh, I already tried that. Opened in Adobe and I see the same as in the viewer in Kile. What about the UTF-8?

Comment: I think you need to Save-As and select the right encoding: https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/extragear-office/kile/lang.html 
It looks like the default is not UTF-8. (But don't follow the rest of the instructions, (`ucs` package; `inputenc` etc, since they don't apply to XeLaTeX.)

Comment: WORKED!!! Would you like to update your answer with these comments or should I mark it accepted as such? And although the rules say don't thank, I'll still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet and trying different ways. I found this useful for latex on Mac.

There are 2 options:

- 1. If you plan to write using the [GurbaniLipi Key Map](https://www.sikhnet.com/files/images/2009/GurbaniLipi-keymap.jpg) then: 
     Download font you would like to use. Variety of options are available on

     - https://www.sikhnet.com/Gurmukhi-Fonts
     - http://www.billie.grosse.is-a-geek.com/resources-03.html
     - https://github.com/GurbaniNow/gurmukhi-fonts (I have not tested the fonts myself yet, but these are used by ShabadOS Desktop)

Once you have the desired `.ttf` file. Once done open Font Book. [image: Font Book] You have the option to have that font available for user or computer. Select the user you want to add or add it to the computer. Now just drag and drop the font in. It will ask you validate or enable the font. Once done the font will be available on your Mac and you can use it with any software. 
Now let's  go ahead and create a `.tex` file to test it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%Set the main languge next as main font.
\setmainfont{Lanma Script Light}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{30}{20}\selectfont
\centerline{isMG}
\end{document}
```

In this `.tex` file we are setting the main font to Gurmukhi. Now typeset it in `XeLaTeX` and you should see the following output. 
[image: .tex file output]

2. If you would like to use the unicode Punjabi letters, then I found it easy to just search in the Font Book on Mac. [image: Font Book search for Gurmukhi font]

Now you can use the unicode Punjabi letters use the following example to test it out. Typeset the `.tex` file in `XeLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%Set the main languge next as main font.
\setmainfont{Lanma Script Light}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{30}{20}\selectfont
ਸਿੰਘ 
\end{document}
```

Once you have the typesetting done. You should have the following output. [image: Unicode typeset file output]

Comment: Welcome to this site! Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Looks like both code snippets are the same; did you plan to have a different file for the second case?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR yes the second one should have text in Unicode ... let me edit it. Thanks for letting me know!