# Unicode characters not displaying in latex

Tags: unicode

I am new to LaTeX. My document has lots of Bengali Unicode sentences and characters. However, it doesn't work with Unicode characters. For example, in the following script, I have a Bengali character  **‘।’(full stop)**. An error occurs due to this Bengali character. The Texmaker shows a square box at the place of the character.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Create a copy of the corpus file; this copied corpus will be converted to the lexicon.
    \item Read the copied corpus file.  
    \item Remove unnecessary punctuations such as, ‘।’(full stop) , ‘,’ (comma) etc.
    \item Remove any foreign words and characters such as an English word.
\end{enumerate}
```

> ```
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character । (U+0964)
> ```

I found a solution in internet which includes the following packages

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

But that is not working working at all. How to show all Bengali Unicode characters and sentences in LaTeX.

Comment: pdfLaTeX only deals with a limited subset of Unicode by default even if you load (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, which is the default in newer LaTeX versions anyway). You would have to set up characters it does not know manually with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. This may work for the odd Bengali punctuation character if it is not used too much and there is a LaTeX equivalent, but if you intend to typeset full-on Bengali text you should probably try XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Only those two engines offer full Unicode support. (Of course you need a font with the characters.)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99606/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285507/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132228/35864 and questions linked there.

Comment: @moewe The OP doesn't seem to respond? Maybe we should use the links that you provide as duplicates.